# R code check for bootsrapping ChiSq Median Estimation

Tags: r, median, montecarlo, confidence-interval, chi-squared

I have a homework problem to write a function that bootstraps its way to finding the 95% CI of a df = 2 Chisq distribution median. My function seems to work, but from wiki I get the formula for the median as k(1 - 2/9k)^3 which yields .343 for k = 2. My function's CI is estimated at (1.28, 1.51) with a plenty large distribution, sample size, and number of simulations (100000). So the theoretical answer isn't anywhere in that interval. Can someone tell me where my code is failing please?

```
ChisqMedian_CI <- function(chiN, nsim, sampleN){
y <- rchisq(n=chiN, df=2)
medy_resample <- NULL
for (i in 1:nsim) {
  y_resample <- sample(y, replace=TRUE, size=sampleN)
  medy_resample[i] <- median(y_resample)
}
  LB <- quantile(medy_resample, probs=c(0.025))
  UB <- quantile(medy_resample, probs=c(0.975))
  return(c(LB, UB))
}
```

Comment: Maybe the answers to this question help somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53533829/6574038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The median of a chi-squared distributed random variable is approximately 
   k * (1 - 2 / (9k))^3. For k = 2, this is about 1.4. This is in line with your results.
2. For (standard) bootstrap, the bootstrap samples are always as large as the original sample. So `chiN` is not necessary and would be set to `sampleN`.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I guess I missed a necessary parenthesis or something when calculating that median manually in R. I did not realize 2 either. That was never made explicit to me before but makes perfect sense.